# How to create sub app out of parent app with single code base in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, web-applications

I have a scenario in which say I have a parent react web app1 which has say features ranging from 1-10. Now I have to create another app2 which should only have features 5-7.I want to host both the apps differently but the sub features in app2 would be exact sub set of web app 1. I don't want to create a separate repo for app2 and duplicate the same code. Is there any way to utilize the code from app1 to create app2 with single repo.

Comment: Make a separate repo that contains all the shared components (which sounds like just features 5-7).

Comment: Similar to  what @Barryman9000 said you can create and publish your react web app1 components as a private package following these [steps](https://medium.com/groftware/how-to-publish-your-react-component-on-npm-9cf48d91944d) and then import the feature that you need.